# StringTokenizer -How to ignore spaces within a string

Tags: java, string

I am trying to use a stringtokenizer on a list of words as below

```
String sentence=""Name":"jon" "location":"3333 abc street" "country":"usa"" etc
```

When i use stringtokenizer and give space as the delimiter as below

```
StringTokenizer tokens=new StringTokenizer(sentence," ")
```

I was expecting my output as different tokens as below

```
Name:jon

location:3333 abc street

country:usa
```

But the string tokenizer tries to tokenize on the value of location also and it appears like

```
Name:jon

location:3333

abc

street

country:usa
```

Please let me know how i can fix the above and if i need to do a regex what kind of the expression should i specify?

Comment: `StringTokenizer` is too simple-minded for this job. Consider using regular expressions or do your own parsing. Are you going to need to deal with quote marks inside the values themselves?

Comment: I will be using the quote marks with values as such in the output file without any processing i.e location:"333 abc street"

Comment: I was referring to quote marks within values, not around them (e.g., `Name:Fred ("Freddy") Jones`. Obviously, they would have to be escaped somehow.

Answer (score 5):

This can be easily handled using a [CSV Reader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/).

```
String str = "\"Name\":\"jon\" \"location\":\"3333 abc street\" \"country\":\"usa\"";

// prepare String for CSV parsing
CsvReader reader = CsvReader.parse(str.replaceAll("\" *: *\"", ":"));
reader.setDelimiter(' '); // use space a delimiter
reader.readRecord(); // read CSV record
for (int i=0; i<reader.getColumnCount(); i++) // loop thru columns
    System.out.printf("Scol[%d]: [%s]%n", i, reader.get(i));
```

#### Update: And here is pure Java SDK solution:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+?)(\\s+(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
for (int i=0; m.find(); i++)
    System.out.printf("Scol[%d]: [%s]%n", i, m.group(1).replace("\"", ""));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Scol[0]: [Name:jon]
Scol[1]: [location:3333 abc street]
Scol[2]: [country:usa]
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/WO0NK6

#### Explanation: As per OP's comments:

I am using this regex:

```
(.+?)(\\s+(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)|$)
```

Breaking it down now into smaller chunks.

PS: DQ represents Double quote

```
(?:[^\"]*\")                    0 or more non-DQ characters followed by one DQ (RE1)
(?:[^\"]*\"){2}                 Exactly a pair of above RE1
(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*            0 or more occurrences of pair of RE1
(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$     0 or more occurrences of pair of RE1 followed by 0 or more non-DQ characters followed by end of string (RE2)
(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$) Positive lookahead of above RE2

.+?  Match 1 or more characters (? is for non-greedy matching)
\\s+ Should be followed by one or more spaces
(\\s+(?=RE2)|$) Should be followed by space or end of string
```

**In short:** It means match 1 or more length any characters followed by "a space OR end of string". Space must be followed by **EVEN number of DQs**. Hence space outside double quotes will be matched and inside double quotes will not be matched (since those are followed by **odd number of DQs**).

Comment: Do you really want nulls embedded in the output? Much better to `replace("\"", "")`.

Comment: @anubhava can you explain the pattern matching solution in detail especially the pattern.  +1 for the solution.

Comment: @Raghunandan: Sure I will add the explanation to my answer in few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

StringTokenizer is too simple-minded for this job. If you don't need to deal with quote marks inside the values, you can try this regex:

```
String s = "\"Name\":\"jon\" \"location\":\"3333 abc street\" \"country\":\"usa\"";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output:

> Name
>   jon
>   location
>   3333 abc street
>   country
>   usa

This won't handle internal quote marks within values—where the output should be, e.g.,

> Name:Fred ("Freddy") Jones

Answer (score 1):

You can use Json, Its looks like You are using Json kind of schema.
Do a bit google and try to implement Json.

```
String sentence=""Name":"jon" "location":"3333 abc street" "country":"usa"" etc
```

Will be key, value pair in Json like name is key and Jon is value. location is key and 3333 abc street is value. and so on....

Give it a try.
Here is one link
http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/

Edit:
Its just a bit silly answer, But You can try something like this,
sentence = sentence.replaceAll("\" ", "*");
StringTokenizer tokens=new StringTokenizer(sentence,"*");

Comment: It would be JSON if there were commas between elements and braces around the whole thing.

Comment: I dont want to use JSON library since the text is not exactly in JSON format .